# Moving jQuery code into a function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I apply when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $('#updateDialog').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          width: 400,
          resizable: false,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Update": function () {
                  $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue                         
                  $("#updateReferenceForm").submit();
              },
              "Cancel": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });

  });
```

Is there a way that I can take the actions of this code and move it to a function.  Then just have a one line call to this function inside my $(document).ready(function () {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's very simple:

```
function foo()
{
       $('#updateDialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 400,
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          "Update": function () {
              $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue                         
              $("#updateReferenceForm").submit();
          },
          "Cancel": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      }
  });      
}

// First way:
$(function(){
    foo();
});

// Second way:
$(document).ready(function () {
    foo()
});

// Mathias Bynens version to save conflicts with global vars.
(function() {
     var foo = function() { /* do something */};
     $(foo); 
 }()
 );
```

Comment: Even shorter: `$(foo)`. Note for OP. When the jQuery constructor is called with a function as an argument, its short for `$(document).ready(foo);`.

Comment: This will create a global variable (`foo`), which is something that should be avoided.

Comment: @RobW, Didn't finished editing the answer, I added it later... =)

Comment: @MathiasBynens. He can call the function anything he wants, I can't choose a name that fits to some unknown application...

Comment: @gdoron It’s not about the variable name `foo`, it’s about polluting the global namespace in general. It would be better to add this to the global `jQuery` object instead.

Comment: @Mathias - What do you mean it would be better to add this to the global jQuery object?

Comment: @Samantha Let’s say you name your global function `foo`, and then you include some other library that uses this name as well. Stuff will break. You could avoid this by using an IIFE: `(function() { var foo = function() { /* do something */}; $(foo); }());` or by extending `jQuery`: `$.foo = function() { /* do something */}; $($.foo);`

Comment: @MathiasBynens, Added your solution. Tell me if you have more helpful comments.

Comment: @gdoron - I'm a bit confused with your addition. Should I still create the function in the same way but just call it differently? Can you show where to create and where to call. Thanks very much

Comment: @Samantha2, Replace `/* do something */` with your's code. It's too long to duplicate it.

Comment: @gdoron -  But then how do I call it. Just by doing : $($.foo);  ?  Sorry to keep asking questions but it is confusing for me.

Comment: @Samantha2, You don't need to call it. It's already being called. after the definition of `foo` it's being called. Just copy and test it .

Comment: @gdoron - But the question was about taking the code, moving it out of the document ready section and then having a one line call to that code in document ready.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use this sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyBlah("hello");
});

function MyBlah(blah) {
    alert(blah);
}
```